# How important is it for C# developer to know IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

To what extent does a C# developer have to know about IIS ?  Minimum areas / knowledge required ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It entirely depends on the context. If you're not doing ASP.NET, then you really don't need to know it at all :)

If you're doing ASP.NET but you have system administrators who will work with you to find out your requirements and manage all the worker pools etc, you don't need to know an awful lot. (Although I'd say it's important to understand the basics in terms of AppDomain recycling, sessions, scaling out as well as up.)

If you're going to deploy it yourself, I would look at:

- Worker pools
- Impersonation and permissions (who you're going to run as)
- AppDomain recycling
- Session management
- Load balancing and how it will affect your particular situation
- Other IIS options such as compression

Comment: I suppose the other context in which you'd need IIS knowledge is if you wrote applications which manipulated IIS in some way - even just turning it off and on or manipulating simple settings via API.

Comment: True - although at that point you need to know entirely different things :)

Comment: Jon, what books / resource would you recommend to learn about the topics you mentioned ?  Thanks.

Comment: @Michael: I'm afraid I don't have any particular suggestions on that front :(

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Jon Skeet said:

Starting with IIS7 you can do a lot more with [modules/handlers](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/366/developing-iis-70-modules-and-handlers-with-the-net-framework/) written in .NET than was possible before. Therefore it would probably be a good idea to look at the [IIS7 architecture](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/101/introduction-to-iis7-architecture/) and the [request processing](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/101/introduction-to-iis7-architecture/#Request) (I have to say, that I haven't yet looked at these things in detail, but it's on my list).